# Define protected class methods from module - ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to give a class a protected method via modules which can only be called by itself and other classes inheriting them. I'd like to hide the method from being used by Class.method and only be accessible to the Class class internally or subclasses that inherit Class. How would I go about doing this? This is what I have so far.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
module ProtectedClassMethods
  @class_instance_var = 1234567

  def included(base); base.extend(ProtectedClassMethods); end

  protected

  def protected_class_method; puts "A PROTECTED CLASS METHOD => #{@class_instance_var}"; end
end

class Class1
  def value; "Class1"; end
end

class Class2 < Class1
  extend ProtectedClassMethods
  class << self
    protected_class_method #crashes here
  end
  def value; "Class2"; end

end

class Class3 < Class2
  class << self
    @class_instance_var = 24681012
    protected_class_method
  end 
  def value; "Class3"; end
end



puts "Initializing Class1"
class1 = Class1.new
puts "Done (Class1)"

puts "Initializing Class2"
class2 = Class2.new
puts "Done (Class2)"

puts "Initializing Class3"
class3 = Class3.new
puts "Done (Class3)"

puts class1.value
puts class2.value
puts class3.value
```

gives this error

```
./protected_class_test.rb:20:in `singletonclass': undefined local variable or method `protected_class_method' for #<Class:Class2> (NameError)
        from ./protected_class_test.rb:18:in `<class:Class2>'
        from ./protected_class_test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working thing.

```
module ProtectedClassMethods
  @class_instance_var = 1234567

  def included(base); base.extend(ProtectedClassMethods); end

  protected

  def protected_class_method; puts "A PROTECTED CLASS METHOD => #{@class_instance_var}"; end
end

class Class1
  def value; "Class1"; end
end

class Class2 < Class1
  extend ProtectedClassMethods
  protected_class_method #crashes here
  def value; "Class2"; end

end

class Class3 < Class2
  @class_instance_var = 24681012
  protected_class_method
  def value; "Class3"; end
end



puts "Initializing Class1"
class1 = Class1.new
puts "Done (Class1)"
```

Doing

```
class << self
  protected_class_method #crashes here
end
```

You were actually calling the method on the meta class (the class of the class) and the method was defined on the class itself.